# MS DOS 'for' command to access file contents -- spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

If a.txt contains

```
a b c
abc
```

The command `for /f %x in (a.txt) do echo %x` is printing

```
a
abc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually mean MS-DOS, or do you mean the windows command line?

Comment: @skaffman Windows command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %x in (a.txt) do @echo %x
```

The @echo will prevent the echo line from being printed

[image: The For loop example]

Comment: Neat; but does not echo `a b c` as the string. I still see `a`.

Comment: funny how i never noticed the tokens part :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=|" %i in (a.txt) do @echo %i
```

Inside "delims=|" you can use any character for the delimiter that is not part of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a IN ("a.txt") DO (
    if not "%%a"=="" echo.%%a
    if not "%%b"=="" echo.%%b
    if not "%%c"=="" echo.%%c
)
```

Tokens - the set of chars delimited by one of the delim char.
You can specify many delim chars, i.e. `delims= .,`